# What is this noise from next door?

Tags: noise, building

There’s a strange mechanical whirr coming from the building next door. It buzzes every four minutes.

Listen here: https://clyp.it/3qwn1qhc

We keep the windows open in our bedroom during the winter so this is been wreaking havoc on our sleep.

More info: we’re on the fifth floor and just above the roof of the building next door which has a laundromat below and a sports bar on the second floor. Also, the sports bar was closed for awhile and recently reopened after renovations.

Comment: It sounds like some piece of equipment trying to start.  An HVAC compressor, a commercial refrigerator, an air compressor, etc.  Have you contacted the building tenant?

Comment: Not yet, but I’m planning on contacting them later today.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like it is trying , probably overheating and shutting down that would explain a 4 minute cycle.

Comment: it sounds like the clothes dryer is buzzing alerting that the clothes are dry.

Comment: I'm voting to close. The OP hasn't bee back to clarify question.